# Shell: store and display result from an async/network command

Tags: java, bash, shell, jar, terminal

I have a java command:

```
java -jar app.jar getToken
```

this, on executing, prompts like this:

```
user:
pass:
```

After entering the `user` and `pass`, the java app contacts the server and returns a result:

```
token: 32nd3d4
```

I want to store the result in a variable and display it.

How do i do that with shell scripts?

i've tried:

```
res=$(java -jar app.jar getToken)
echo $res
```